# How to query multiple COUNT(*) with good performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, postgresql-9.2

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
schedule_id serial NOT NULL,
start_date date,
CONSTRAINT schedule_id PRIMARY KEY (schedule_element_id)
)
```

And this table:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule_user (
schedule_user_id serial NOT NULL,
schedule_id integer,
state int,
CONSTRAINT fk_schedule_id   FOREIGN KEY (schedule_id)
      REFERENCES schedule (schedule_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

```
schedule 
 -------------------------
|schedule_id |date        |
|------------+------------|
|1           |'2013-10-10'|
|2           |'2013-10-20'|
|3           |'2013-08-13'|
 -------------------------

schedule_user 
 -----------------------------------
|schedule_user_id|schedule_id |state|
|----------------+------------+-----|
|1               | 1          |0    |
|2               | 1          |1    |
|3               | 1          |2    |
|4               | 1          |0    |
|5               | 1          |1    |
|6               | 1          |1    |
|4               | 2          |0    |
|5               | 2          |1    |
|7               | 2          |0    |
|2               | 3          |1    |
 -----------------------------------
```

And I want a table like this:

```
characteristic
 ---------------------------------------
|schedule_id |state0|state1|state2|total|
|------------+------+------+------+-----|
|1           |2     |3     |1     |6    |
|2           |2     |1     |0     |3    |
|3           |1     |1     |0     |2    |
 ---------------------------------------
```

I've made this query that looks as as horrible as it's performance.

```
SELECT 
    schedule.schedule_id AS id, 
    (( SELECT count(*) AS count
         FROM schedule_user
         WHERE schedule_user.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id
           AND state=0))::integer AS state0, 
    (( SELECT count(*) AS count
         FROM schedule_user
         WHERE schedule_user.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id
           AND state=1))::integer AS state1,
    (( SELECT count(*) AS count
         FROM schedule_user
         WHERE schedule_user.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id
           AND state=2))::integer AS state2,          
    (( SELECT count(*) AS count
         FROM schedule_user
         WHERE schedule_user.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id))::integer
       AS total
  FROM schedule
```

Is there a better way to perform such a query?
Should I create an Index to 'state' column? if so, how should it look like?

Comment: What you want to do is a pivot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to make a pivot table. An easy way to make one in SQL if you know all of the possible values of state beforehand is using `sum` and `case` statements.

```
select schedule_id,
       sum(case state when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as state0,
       sum(case state when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as state1,
       sum(case state when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as state2,
       count(*) as total
from schedule_user
group by schedule_id;
```

Another way is to use the [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) table function.

Neither of these will let you get away with not knowing the set of values of state (and hence the columns in the result set).

Answer (score 3):

I would try

```
SELECT s.schedule_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN su.state = 0 THEN 1 END) AS state0,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN su.state = 1 THEN 1 END) AS state1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN su.state = 2 THEN 1 END) AS state2,
       COUNT(su.state) AS total
  FROM schedule s
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN schedule_user su
    ON su.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
 GROUP
    BY s.schedule_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ths standard approach is to use SUM() with a CASE over a JOIN with a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
schedule.schedule_id AS id, 
SUM (case when state=0 then 1 else 0 end) AS state0, 
SUM (case when state=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS state1, 
SUM (case when state=2 then 1 else 0 end) AS state2, 
count(*) AS total
FROM schedule
LEFT JOIN schedule_user
  ON schedule_user.schedule_id = schedule.schedule_id
GROUP BY 1
```